Mobile Safari crashes and some time reload when i am stay on site 3 minutes
I am facing an issue on the mobile Safari browser. Sometimes the website refreshes automatically, and sometimes Safari crashes. My website is made in Angular 17. Does anyone have any solutions for this? It's working fine everywhere, even on Mac, except for the mobile Safari browser.
Yesterday, I tried to address that issue but was unable to identify the cause.

Use the Safari Developer Tools to check for any console errors or warnings that appear.

i already checked in safari developer tools but there is no error  found there and not even warning.
its working perfectly on safari and chrome browser on mac but on mobile safari its not working , some time reload the page and sometime crash the safari browser.

@KhaledAyed  do you have any solutions for the memory leakage in mobile safari ?

Angular is supposed to support the latest browsers including Safari.. Well i recommend you to use https://saucelabs.com/ as a tester for the application in different platforms and browsers.
